# How do I write a Flycheck predicate that checks for the checkers config file

Tags: flycheck

Suppose I have the following [Flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/) checker:

```el
(flycheck-def-config-file-var flycheck-jscs
                              javascript-jscs
                              ".jscs"
                              :safe #'stringp)

(flycheck-define-checker javascript-jscs
                         "A jscs code style checker."
                         :command ("jscs" "--reporter" "checkstyle"
                                   (config-file "--config" flycheck-jscs) source)
                         :error-parser flycheck-parse-checkstyle
                         :modes (js-mode js2-mode js3-mode)
                         :next-checkers (javascript-jshint))

(provide 'flycheck-jscs)
```

How do I add a `:predicate` that tells flycheck to disable the checker if `flycheck-jscs` is `nil`?

I only manage to get this message regardless what code I try with:

> Error while checking syntax automatically:
>
> `(invalid-function (quote (not (not (quote flycheck-jscs)))))`

Comment: A little extra bit of info: jscs is a style checker for JavaScript. You define your style in a .jscs file. If that file doesn't exist, running the checker doesn't make much sense so the goal is to disable the checking them altogether.

Comment: What about the `:predicate` property ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: I overlooked the colon...  It would be easier, if you'd posted what value you've tried.  But judging from the output, you used a sexp rather than a function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you tried to pass a sexp rather than a function.  The argument to `:predicate` needs to be a proper function, that is, a `lambda` in your case:

```
:predicate (lambda () flycheck-jscs)
```

I'm pretty sure that I documented this, so I wonder why you tried it in a different way.  Did you find the documentation lacking or unclear?  I'd love to fix it, if possible.

There's little use in the double negation, by the way.  Flycheck only tests for truthy-ness, but never for `t`.

Comment: Hm, you are correct, my ELisp is really not that great, I was passing a sexp just like you say.

That specific line still didn't work though, jscs is still being called even if there's no .jscs file.